# API EntityTag-Create, tags not added if one already exists on contact

Tags: api

We are trying to  mass updating tags via API.

Using API. When trying to add an array of tags Example: ["1","2","3"] to a contact using API : EntityTag-Create.  The set of tags are not added whenever one of the tags is already assigned to contact.

In result shows "not added":"1"

Found in versions 4.6.11-0 thru 4.7.6-0